# DetailViewController with UIView causes "Unrecognized Selector" error when selecting row in table

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a table view with a list of categories that I would like the user to be able to select in order to rate. I've created a separate UIView (RateView) to manage the ratings within the detailviewcontroller.

I'm able to get the ratings to work fine when developing independently of the project and without a table. However, when incorporating the code for tracking ratings into storyboard and with a table, I receive the following error when attempting to navigate from the table to the detail view: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setNotSelectedImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad9b280' (notSelectedImage is a property of the UIView titled RateView).

Below are the interface files for each of the referenced view controllers.

*** RatingsList_ViewController ***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Rate_ViewController.h"

@interface RatingsList_ViewController : UITableViewController

- (IBAction)dismissModal:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is the SEGUE within the table to Rate_ViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toRateDetail" sender:self];
    Rate_ViewController *rateCategory;
    rateCategory = (Rate_ViewController *) self.navigationController;   
}
```

*** Rate_ViewController ***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RateView.h"

@interface Rate_ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, RateViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet RateView *rateView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *notesField;

@end
```

I suspect that I've not delegated properly but any assistance you could provide would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would appear from the error message that the view you're calling that method on is a UIView not your subclass, rateView. Is rateView a view you created in the storyboard? Did you remember to change its class to rateView?

Comment: RateView (UIView) is a subclass of Rate_ViewController (UIViewController). I created Rate_ViewController in storyboard and added the UIView element (RateView) to that screen. I then added an outlet to Rate_ViewController and bound that to the RateView UIView.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense -- RateView can't be both a UIView and a subclass of Rate_ViewController (do you mean it's a subview of Rate_ViewController's view?). I'll ask my question, that I asked in my first comment again -- did you change the class of the view you added to Rate_ViewController in IB (assuming that RateView is a subclass of UIView)??

Comment: rdelmar, you are correct. RateView is a subview of Rate_ViewController. And apologies for the earlier omission, the detail view controller has been assigned Rate_ViewController.